# How to check which list is the source table of a lookup field?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a lookup column called Function group index. I am new to sharePoint. Is it possible to check which list this column is referring? Thanks very much.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could find in "Get information from:". :)
For this one, the list or library name is "Function group index".

Answer (score 1):

The parameter `Get Information from` shows the list name you are referring for the lookup.